# how to change space with "-" in search bar input

Tags: php, html, search, input, submit

When I insert a text I want to change space with "-" in a search bar (from "Samsung S7 Edge" to "Samsung-S7-Edge"). Here is my code :

```
<!-- BEGIN: search -->
<div id="search">
   <form action="{INSTALLDIR}index.php" method="get" name="searchprod" id="prodsearch">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
         <tr>
            <td><input name="ps" type="text" id="searchbox" value="Cauta produse...ex. samsung-s7-edge" onfocus="this.value=''; this.style.color='#333333';" />
               <input type="hidden" name="sv" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Cauta" class="searchButton" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
<!-- END: search -->
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to do this as the user is typing or on the search results page after they hit submit?

Comment: Please share, what you have achieved ? Some piece of code for that logic

Comment: Thank's for replay Serg Chernata.Yes, i want to do this as the user is typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I created a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxmotdLx/1/) - which should work.

**So what it is doing:**

If a person is triggering the keypress event and the character typed is a space (char 32) I prevent the event and instead get the current value of the field and add a dash `-`.

**What it is not doing:**

If someone is pasting text, there is no keypress event and therefore no replacing of the space character.

Comment: This code is just an example. But usually you should add it in your script tag  at the bottom of your page.

Comment: i put but is not working. i put like <script>
(function() {
  var searchElement = document.getElementById('search');
  searchElement.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
      searchElement.value = searchElement.value + '-';
    }
  });
})();

</script>

Comment: did you also add `id="search"` to your input field?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the keyboard related events, that occur in this sequence:

1. onkeydown (when the user is pressing a key)
2. onkeypress (when the user presses a key)
3. onkeyup (when the user releases a key)

Here you have plenty of info on [javascript key events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html), or if you are using jquery [key events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/)